# If dropdown menu is selected

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I'm switching from radio buttons `<input type="radio" />`  to a dropdown menu `<select><option value="">~`.

With the radio's I do the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="datumaflevering" value="1 week" <?php if ($row['datumaflevering'] == '1 week') { echo 'checked="checked"';}?> onDblClick="this.checked=false;"/> &nbsp;1
```

Notice the PHP statement. If the date is already in the database it sets it as `checked`. Can I do this with dropdown menu's as well?

```
<select size="1" name="datumaflevering" id="t3">
        <option value="1 week" name="datumaflevering">1 week</option>
        <option value="2 weken" name="datumaflevering">2 weken</option>
        <option value="3 weken" name="datumaflevering">3 weken</option>
        <option value="4 weken" name="datumaflevering">4 weken</option>
        <option value="5 weken" name="datumaflevering">5 weken</option>
        <option value="6 weken" name="datumaflevering">6 weken</option>
        <option value="7 weken" name="datumaflevering">7 weken</option>
        <option value="8 weken" name="datumaflevering">8 weken</option>
        <option value="9 weken" name="datumaflevering">9 weken</option>
        <option value="10 weken" name="datumaflevering">10 weken</option>
        <option value="11 weken" name="datumaflevering">11 weken</option>
        <option value="12 weken" name="datumaflevering">12 weken</option>
        <option value="13 weken" name="datumaflevering">13 weken</option>
        <option value="14 weken" name="datumaflevering">14 weken</option>
    </select>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed. All you have to change is `echo 'checked="checked"'` to `echo 'selected'` (or `echo 'selected="selected"'` if using XHTML).

Answer (score 1):

Yes..

```
<select size="1" name="datumaflevering" id="t3">
        <option value="1 week" name="datumaflevering" <?php if ($row['datumaflevering'] == '1 week') { ?> selected = "selected" <?php } ?>>1 week</option>
        <option value="2 weken" name="datumaflevering">2 weken</option>
        <option value="3 weken" name="datumaflevering">3 weken</option>
        <option value="4 weken" name="datumaflevering">4 weken</option>
        <option value="5 weken" name="datumaflevering">5 weken</option>
        <option value="6 weken" name="datumaflevering">6 weken</option>
        <option value="7 weken" name="datumaflevering">7 weken</option>
        <option value="8 weken" name="datumaflevering">8 weken</option>
        <option value="9 weken" name="datumaflevering">9 weken</option>
        <option value="10 weken" name="datumaflevering">10 weken</option>
        <option value="11 weken" name="datumaflevering">11 weken</option>
        <option value="12 weken" name="datumaflevering">12 weken</option>
        <option value="13 weken" name="datumaflevering">13 weken</option>
        <option value="14 weken" name="datumaflevering">14 weken</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
<select size="1" name="datumaflevering" id="t3" onchange="this.selected=true;">
<option value="1 week" name="datumaflevering" <?php if ($row['datumaflevering'] == '1 week') { ?> selected = "selected" <?php } ?>>1 week</option>
...
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
<option<?php echo ($row['datumaflevering'] == '1 week')? ' selected="selected" : '' ?>>
   Option
</option>
```

for each option...

Answer (score 1):

Better to write a loop in PHP

```
<select size="1" name="datumaflevering" id="t3">

<?php
           for($i =1 ;$i < 15;$i++) {
                 $selected = ($row['datumaflevering'] == '$i weekn') ? 'selected':'';
                 echo "<option value='$i weken' $selected name='datumaflevering'>$i weken";
           }
?>


</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your options in an array, and while looping you can compare the value of each option with your $row to add the required html:

```
<?php
    // your value array...
    $selectOptions = array('1 week','2 weken','...');
?>
<select size="1" name="datumaflevering" id="t3">
    <?php foreach($selectOptions as $opt): 
        $selected = ($opt === $row['datumaflevering']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $opt;?>" name="datumaflevering"<?php echo $selected?>><?php echo $opt;?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
?>
```